# About re- ''Using Alt+Tab in Remmina RDP connection''

Tags: remote, remmina

I wish i am asking this in right place ^_^ cuz i'm new in here and i have a problem and i guess this is not just mine problem. If i am wrong place in this forum, please correct and warn me.

It's about 'Using Alt+Tab in Remmina RDP connection' but with a litle bit difference. Last few days, Remmina is unable to allow me using some shortcuts which like 'alt + tab', 'Win button' or which useable Fn options (like volume increasing etc.)

I tried many more thing and i decide to getting help.

Is this about Remmina or Ubuntu or my machine? Or (maybe) it's about Nvidia settings? Why i think this? Cause i tried one option last days, but now i can't take it back cause the Nvidia X server settings app not working (for all users). Maybe it's relevant with this or not, finally, my remote desktop app can't use these options which i told upper :(

(from now, sorry my insufficient English)

Comment: I solved this issue and i am a happy man now ^_^


Just configure settings for xorg friends. 

 [code] sudo dpkg --configure -a >> for configure the packages.

 (code) sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg >> for add Xorg visual server to system again and for need to set up.

 [code] sudo nvidia-xconfig >> for if you have got a Nvidia card, just do that.

 [code] sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg >> for configure Xorg xserver.

These are solved my issue with tries, take times and love <3

Comment: i tried to edit answer but if you failed to understand or reading the solve step's text, i can post them in a screen shot link. Please write folk ^_^